# Can I backup my MacBook Pro onto my Dell Laptop?

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine, backup

I've used 40 GB of space on my MacBook Pro, and I want to back it up. The only thing I have with enough space is my Dell laptop (500 GB). Is there any way I can back it up onto there? If so, how?

Comment: To help answer your question, can you tell us which versions of OS X and Windows you are using? Also, how comfortable are you with using command line tools? :)

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan OS X 10.9.4 and Windows 8 (latest). Yeah, I know a lot of git and such.

Comment: Do you need to do a one off transfer (for example, are there a lot of large video files you just want to transfer to clear up space) or are you looking for a solution you can use to backup regularly?

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to spend < $100US to purchase a external USB HD (Western Digital, Seagate, and LaCie make good drives,) and use Time Machine to back it up. Time Machine is a very handy and reliable method to backup your entire Mac.

Answer (score 1):

[CrashPlan](http://www.code42.com/crashplan/features/backup-destinations/#local) by Code42 supports backing up data between different operating systems running on local computers:

> Dust off that old computer. It doesn’t even matter which operating system it uses. Install CrashPlan on both computers. Make sure to use the same email address. Your other computers will show up in “Computers” under “Destinations.” Select computer you want to back up. Click “Start Backup.” You’re on your way.

Answer (score 0):

On the Microsoft website there is some information about moving data from a mac to a windows PC: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2636421

Comment: That doesn't say how I can connect the shared folder to time machine. I need to backup my entire mac.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your Dell computer to share a specific directory to a network. There are plenty of articles about sharing files between Windows and Mac.

Once sharing is set up, you can configure Time Machine to backup to your Windows computer.
I would recommend connecting both computers via an ethernet cable, so that backing up would be faster.